# Запись файла в структуру и работа с ней

Tags: c, структуры, файловая-система, файловый-ввод-вывод

Суть задачи: небольшая база данных расположенных в файле(бинарном(предпочтительней) или текстовом).

Проблема в следующем: какие я только сайты не пробовал - то код не работает, то ещё что. Нужно создать массив структур, загрузить в него данные с файла, поработать с ними (добавить запись, редактировать, отобразить их, отсортировать и тд).

Хотелось бы увидеть именно пример работы, то есть пример кода для добавления записи  например и для их отображения. Могу вставить сюда свои наброски, однако не вижу смысла, в интернете их немало а все равно не работает (однако укажу, что использовал функции типа Save и Load для бинарного файла). Хотелось бы, повторюсь, увидеть ***пример*** работы с ними на примере массива указанной структуры.

```
struct DVD{
 char name[20];
 char singer[20];
 char song[20];
 int year;
}
```

В идеале полный код небольшой программы чтобы я понял где и когда использовать функции типа Save и Load и подобных им.

Answer (score -2):

Можно попробовать такой варинт:

```
 // Add record to file
    void addRecord(DVD record) {
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen("dvd.dat", "ab"); // opens file in binary mode
        if (file == NULL) {
            printf("Error opening file!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        fwrite(&record, sizeof(DVD), 1, file); // writes struct to file
        fclose(file);
    }
    
    // Read records from file
    void readRecords() {
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen("dvd.dat", "rb"); // opens file in binary mode
        if (file == NULL) {
            printf("Error opening file!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        DVD record;
        while (fread(&record, sizeof(DVD), 1, file)) { // reads struct from file
            printf("Name: %s\nSinger: %s\nSong: %s\nYear: %d\n", record.name, record.singer, record.song, record.year);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
```

или такой

```
void saveToFile(DVD arr[], int size) {
    ofstream file("dvd.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        file << arr[i].name << " " << arr[i].singer << " " << arr[i].song << " " << arr[i].year &#8203;`oaicite:{"index":0,"invalid_reason":"Malformed citation << endl;\n    }\n    file.close();\n}\n\nvoid loadFromFile(DVD arr[], int &size) {\n    ifstream file(\"dvd.txt\");\n    while (file >> arr[size].name >> arr[size].singer >> arr[size].song >>"}`&#8203; arr[size].year) {
        size++;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Внес исправления в код:

```
void saveToFile(DVD arr[], int size) {
    FILE *file = fopen("dvd.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(arr, sizeof(DVD), size, file);
    fclose(file);
}

void loadFromFile(DVD arr[], int &size) {
    FILE *file = fopen("dvd.bin", "rb");
    size = fread(arr, sizeof(DVD), MAX_SIZE, file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

> Почему мы передаем "&size"? И с МАX_SIZE не хотело работать, я заменил
> просто на размер массива?

Проблема здесь может быть в том, что вы не инициализируете массив при загрузке данных из файла. Вот код для `loadFromFile`:

```
void loadFromFile(DVD arr[], int &size) {
    FILE *file = fopen("dvd.bin", "rb");
    size = fread(arr, sizeof(DVD), size, file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

В этом коде, я убрал использование MAX_SIZE и использовал size.

По поводу передачи `&size` в функцию `loadFromFile`, это нужно для того, чтобы мы могли изменять значение переменной `size` внутри функции. Если мы бы передавали `size` без адресного оператора `&`, то значение `size` внутри функции было бы копией значения `size` из внешней области видимости и изменение его внутри функции не повлияло бы на значение `size` вне функции.

По поводу второй части вопроса проблема здесь может быть связана с тем, что вы записываете данные в файл только после ввода новых данных, а не после загрузки данных из файла. Вам нужно вызывать функцию `saveToFile` сразу же после загрузки данных из файла, чтобы сохранить измененные данные.

```
DVD dvd[10];
loadFromFile(dvd, 10);
printf(" Enter a name of DVD: "); scanf("%s", &dvd[4].name);
printf(" Enter a singer: "); scanf("%s", &dvd[4].singer);
printf(" Enter a year: "); scanf("%d", &dvd[4].year);
printDVD();
saveToFile(dvd, 10);
```

Если же это не решает проблему, можно проверить содержимое файла после каждой операции сохранения и загрузки данных. Тут подойдёт `fseek` и `fread`, чтобы определить, где именно происходит ошибка.

МЫ передаем `"&size"` это нужно чтобы передать размер структуры по ссылке и изменить его внутри функции, так как при передаче по значению функция получает копию значения и изменения внутри функции не влияют на значение вне функции.

Comment: А в последнем примере (кстати, подправили бы его) почему вы решили, что имя, название, исполнитель - все состоят из одного слова?

Comment: Ваш ответ близок к идеальному, однако, в функции чтения вы ещё и выводите данные, а мне нужно записать их в структуру чтобы дальше с ней работать. Например я работал с массивом структур ДВД, у меня было два полностью заполненных элемента, в конце программы я должен загрузить их в файл, а при следующем запуске данные должны загрузиться в тот-же массив структур чтобы я снова мог с ними работать. Заранее извиняюсь за свою недалёкость, я новичок, и Си - мой первый язык программирования.

Comment: написал корректный код, проверьте

Comment: Простите, но мне нужно решение именно на си, и ранее вы считывали с бинарного файла, а в последнем решении с текстового. Я понимаю что докучаю вам, просто это задание действительно важно. Функцию вывода я уже написал отдельно, осталось только понять как записывать данные из файла в массив структур и как в этот массив что-то записать.

Comment: @SomeName `именно на си` , а у вас метка на любом языке. Вы определитесь с метками сначала.

Comment: посмотрите, подойдет ли такой код

Comment: Метки исправил. Функции вроде работают, однако при следующем порядке действий:      
 ```DVD dvd[10];

    dvd[1] = { "Bandana", "Kizaru", "Bandana", 2022 };

    loadFromFile(dvd, 10);

    printf(" Enter a name of DVD: "); scanf("%s", &dvd[4].name);
    printf(" Enter a singer: "); scanf("%s", &dvd[4].singer);
    printf(" Enter a year: "); scanf("%d", &dvd[4].year);
    printDVD();
    saveToFile(dvd, 10); ``` . Введённые данные держаться только при втором запуске программы. То есть первый запуск - ввел, второй оно мне отобразило, третий - все пропало.

Comment: И еще вопрос ко второй функции. Почему мы передаем "&size"? И с МАX_SIZE не хотело работать, я заменил просто на размер массива.

Comment: ответил на комментарий в ответе

Comment: В C это `void loadFromFile(..., int &size) {...}` не скомпилируется.

Comment: Спасибо, пока, вроде, роботает все что мне нужно. Еще раз спасибо огромное за помощь.